# %s showing strange behavior in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in which I want to find some words preceding a parenthesis. Lets say the string is -

> 'there are many people in the world having colorectal cancer (crc) who also have the depression syndrome (ds)'

I want to capture at most 5 words before a parenthesis. I have a list `acronym_list` of abbreviations which are inside the brackets - `[(crc), (ds)]`. So I am using the following code -

```
acrolen=5
rt=[]
for acro in acronym_list:
    find_words= re.findall('((?:\w+\W+){1,%d}%s)'  %(acrolen, acro), text, re.I)
    for word in find_words:
            rt.append(word)
print rt
```

But this gives this result -

```
('the world having colorectal cancer (crc', 'crc')
('also have the depression syndrome (ds', 'ds')
```

Whereas if I use the regex -

`find_words= re.findall('((?:\w+\W+){1,%d}\(crc\))'  %(acrolen),s, re.I)`

Then it is able to find exactly what I want i.e. -

```
the world having colorectal cancer (crc)
```

The question is - why using `%s` for the string here causing the regex match to be so vastly different (having unnecessary brackets around it, repeating the acronym etc..)

How can I use the 1st regex properly so that I can automate the process using a loop rather than having to enter the exact string every time in the regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the variables you pass are escaped correctly so as to be used as literal text inside a regex pattern. Use `re.escape(acro)`:

```
import re
text = "there are many people in the world having colorectal cancer (crc) who also have the depression syndrome (ds)"
acrolen=5
rt=[]
acronym_list = ["(crc)", "(ds)"]
for acro in acronym_list:
    p = r'((?:\w+\W+){1,%d}%s)' %(acrolen, re.escape(acro))
    # Or, use format:
    # p = r'((?:\w+\W+){{1,{0}}}{1})'.format(acrolen, re.escape(acro))
    find_words= re.findall(p, text, re.I)
    for word in find_words:
        rt.append(word)
print rt
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9lwLYm)

Also, note you do not need to enclose the whole pattern with a capturing group, `re.findall` will return match values if no capturing group is defined in the pattern.

It is also recommended to use raw string literals when defining regex patterns to avoid ambiguous situations.

Comment: thanks a lot, this was very informative. However could you explain how `{{1,{0}}}{1}` worked the same as `{1,%d}%s` ?

Comment: In the format string, the `{n}` is a placeholder for an argument to the method. To denote a literal brace, it must be doubled.